# Not able to obtain Facebook access token

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two pages, facebook.php and generatePageToken.php I'm trying to post as page to my facebook page but this script currently only posts as admin. In the facebook.php page I try and get an access token but it doesn't work - it alerts back blank. Please do not tell me to read some API, I have read it all and I truly do not understand what's wrong with this. I'd ideally like a permanent token if someone could swing it

facebook.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function SendToFacebook()
        {
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                // init the FB JS SDK
                FB.init({
                    appId: '432036336937975',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
                    status: false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                    xfbml: true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
                });


                FB.login(function (response) {
                    FB.api('/me/accounts', function (apiresponse) {
if (response.authResponse) {
        //simple user access token
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken,
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            pageId = '1521533601413118';

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
                //print out the extended page access token
                alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        ajaxRequest.open('POST','generatePageToken.php?pageId=' + pageId, true);
        ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajaxRequest.send('accessToken=' + accessToken);
    }

                        var data = {
                            message: "mymessage test",
                            display: 'iframe',
                            caption: "caption",
                            name: "name",
                            description: "description",
                            to: '1521533601413118',
                            from: '1521533601413118'
                        };

                        FB.api('/1521533601413118/feed', 'post', data, function () {
                            console.log(arguments);
                        });


                    });

                }, { scope: 'manage_pages'});

            };
            // Load the SDK asynchronously
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="SendToFacebook();">Submit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

generatePageToken.php

```
<?php
$accessToken = $_GET['accessToken'];
$pageId = $_POST['pageId'];
$fbAppId = '432036336937975';
$fbAppSecret = 'REMOVED FOR NOW';

$appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $accessToken, $fbAppSecret);
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook-php-3.2');

//get extended user access token
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token' .
    '&client_id=' . $fbAppId .
    '&client_secret=' . $fbAppSecret .
    '&fb_exchange_token=' . $accessToken .
    '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
$response_params = array();
parse_str($curlResult, $response_params);
$extendedUserToken = $response_params['access_token'];

$appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $extendedUserToken, $fbAppSecret);
//get extended page access token
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageId .
    '?fields=access_token' .
    '&access_token=' . $extendedUserToken .
    '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$pageToken = json_decode($curlResult)->access_token;

echo $pageToken;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you mixed up `$_POST` and `$_GET`:

Your code:

```
ajaxRequest.open('POST','generatePageToken.php?pageId=' + pageId, true);
                                               ^ pageId is GET
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.send('accessToken=' + accessToken);
                  ^ accessToken is POST
```

You're sending `pageId` as a GET variable while `accessToken` is a POST variable.

However, your PHP retrieves the variables as:

```
$accessToken = $_GET['accessToken'];
$pageId = $_POST['pageId'];
```

It should be the other way around, such as:

```
$accessToken = $_POST['accessToken'];
$pageId = $_GET['pageId'];
```

**If you want to post on your page as the page's user, you need to change the scope of your permissions first:**

You need `}, { scope: 'manage_pages, publish_stream'});`, (added publish_stream).

Now, it's very easy to post, simply send a POST request:

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
    'access_token'  => **your access token**,
    'message'       => 'hello world!'
));
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/1521533601413118/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Great catch. Now my alert() gives back an access code. However that test post still is posting as admin and not as page. Any further advice? Where do I go from here? Thank you Dave. Unsure of how to use this access code to post as page

Comment: I believe you're looking for the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). With it, you can test out exactly what you want to retrieve with your access token. For example, with this URL, `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?access_token=***&fields=id%2Cname&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1`, (filling the stars with the access token), will allow me to get the user's ID and Name.

Comment: All I want to do is post a message on my page, as my page. How would I incorporate that in? I don't want to mess with my code and risk screwing anything up.

Comment: If you want to post on your page (as the page's owner/admin), then why is `but this script currently only posts as admin` an issue? The user that authenticates them-self will be the one that's posting. You can simply log in as the page's admin, save the token, and hardcode it into your code (this prevents having to hardcode your username and password into the PHP scripts).

Comment: No I don't want to post as the admin/owner. I want to be the PAGE. For example, my name is Ryan Reese. My page is CodeFundamentals. my current code is only posting as Ryan Reese. I want it posted as CodeFundamenatls (I admin this page)

Comment: Oh! I think I understand now. Okay, then you pretty much need to change the way you get your token. This question is pretty much changed as well. In short, you need to [get an extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens), called manage_pages, then to publish, you use a different URL, as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page).

Comment: If you would be willing to finish my script Dave, I could paypal you some money for your trouble. I imagine it's not too much more work to get this working. I've spent a few days on this and I'm stressed over this to the max.

Comment: I have edited my post, see if you can post on your page. (Remember to regenerate an access token with the new permissions.

Comment: Thank you - where exactly do I put the PHP code though? My JavaScript SDK has a post function in it already - do I take that out?

Comment: When I add that publish stream line, I get this error
SCRIPT5009: 'SendToFacebook' is undefined
File: facebook.php, Line: 69, Column: 22

Comment: Nevermind my mistake with publish_stream. Now I just need to know where to put the PHP code. I just generated a code so I should have an hour or two

Comment: You can login once so you can generate the token, then hardcode the token into your code. Then whenever you want to post to your wall, you can post via PHP.

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate that though David. I'm new at this. At the end of my generatePageToken.php I added it in - don't know where else to. My page token is set as a variable as $pageToken so I just threw that in


$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/1521533601413118/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

Comment: No, you should generate the token once and then copy and paste that token to use. You can have another file where it posts on the page.